# Real Manifold ... Complex Coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, smooth-manifolds

I'm working in an earlier edition of John Lee's book on [smooth manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387954481), and he has a number of problems where he represents a real manifold using complex variables.  For instance in chapter 3 problem 5:

> Consider $\mathbb{S}^3$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$ under the usual identification of $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$.  For each $z = (z^1, z^2) \in \mathbb{S}^3$ define a curve $\gamma_z: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^3$ by $$ \gamma_z(t) = (e^{it}z^1, e^{it}z^2).$$

He subsequently asks for us to compute the coordinate representation of $\gamma_z(t)$ using stereographic projection and then also compute $\gamma_z'(t)$ under the same coordinate transformation.  I'm really confused about to do this using complex variables when we're working in a real manifold.  Out of stubbornness I computed what I thought would be the real representation of $\gamma_z(t)$:

$$
\gamma_x(t) \;\; =\;\; (x^1 \cos t - x^2 \sin t, x^1 \sin t + x^2 \cos t, x^3 \cos t - x^4 \sin t, x^3 \sin t + x^4 \cos t)
$$

but this can't possibly be right.  Letting $\sigma:\mathbb{S}^3/\{N\} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the stereographic projection from the neighborhood omitting the point $N = (0,0,0,1)$, we then obtain

$$
(\sigma\circ \gamma_x)(t) \;\; =\;\; \frac{(x^1 \cos t - x^2 \sin t, x^1 \sin t + x^2 \cos t, x^3 \cos t - x^4 \sin t)}{1 - x^3\sin t - x^4 \cos t}
$$

which can't possibly be right since it's not defined at the point $(0,0,1,0)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm lost as to how to tackle this kind of problem using complex variables.  Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** For reference, my copy is a Chinese edition but I don't think there's any substantive difference between my copy and the one posted in the link.  I definitely do not have the second edition.

Comment: @JackLee You're needed.

Comment: Why is this not defined at $(0,0,1,0)$?

Comment: You wrote $x^4\sin t$ for $x^4\cos t$ in your real coordinate expression.

Comment: @John What I obtain when I plug in those coordinates is the vector $\frac{(0,0,\cos t)}{1 - \sin t}$ and this is not defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ since it blows up whenever $t = (2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}, \; k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks for catching that.  I corrected it now.

Comment: $(0,0,1,0)$ is not the same as saying $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (0,0,1,0)$. Also, even if it is undefined doesn't mean that you've done anything wrong. It might happens that your curves will hit $(0,0,0,1)$ at some $t$ (which is clearly plausible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formulas are fine. The "coordinate representation" of a map from $\mathbb R$ into a manifold is generally defined only on a subset of $\mathbb R$, namely the subset that maps into the domain of the coordinates. In this case, the domain of stereographic coordinates is $U = \mathbb S^3\smallsetminus \{(0,0,0,1)\}$. For any $z$ of the form $z=(0,z^2)$ (or $(0,0,x^3,x^4)$ in real coordinates), there will be infinitely many values of $t$ for which $\gamma_z(t)$ is not in the domain of stereographic coordinates. For example, as you noted, if $z = (0,0,1,0)$, then $\gamma_z(t)\notin U$ when $t$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, so the coordinate representation of $\gamma_z$ is not defined for these values of $t$.

Comment: Dr. Lee, thank you for your input.  In general when one can represent a real manifold using complex variables, is it necessary to convert the complex coordinates into their real counterparts (as I did above), or is there usually a "nicer" way to do it using complex variables?  Another problem in your book that comes to mind is proving the power map $p:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $p(z) = z^n$ is smooth, where $z = e^{it}$.

Comment: @Mnifldz: In real manifold theory, it's best to think of complex coordinates just as a shorthand way of expressing formulas involving real coordinates. If you want to apply any of the theory involving tangent vectors, differentials, differential forms, etc., you basically have to convert to real coordinates.